# Dating CMS ideas

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

My boss just told me I have to create a dating website of one of our domains. I was wondering if you guys can give me an idea of a good dating CMS ? It doesn't matter if its paid or not. I installed Dolphin 7 but its too heavy for our needs. I need something that looks nice and supports different languages (if it includes Bulgarian it would be superb)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any CMS platforms specifically for dating sites, but if you're looking for alternative social network platforms to Dolphin 7, you could try one of these:

- [Diaspora](https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/wiki/Installing-and-Running-Diaspora)
- [elgg](http://www.elgg.org/)
- [SocialEngine](http://www.socialengine.net/)
- [phpFox](http://www.phpfox.com/)
- [noserub](http://noserub.com/)

You could also go with a hosted solution:

- [Ning](http://www.ning.com/)
- [SocialGO](http://www.socialgo.com/)
- [groupsite](http://www.groupsite.com/)
- [YoolinkPro](http://www.yoolinkpro.com/)

If price is no option, here are some social media solutions for enterprise customers:

- [onesite](http://www.onesite.com/)
- [kickapps](http://www.kickapps.com/)
- [OmniSocial](http://www.mzinga.com/)
- [SocialSpring](http://socialspring.com/)
- [Moxie](http://www.moxiesoft.com/)
- [ingagenetworks](http://www.ingagenetworks.com/)
- [Concursive](http://www.concursive.com/)
- [telligent community](http://telligent.com/)

However, if Dolphin 7 already does everything you need, then you could just get a support/deployment package from Boonex. It'd be a lot cheaper, and they'd basically setup and customize the site for you.

Comment: +1, great list. Does anyone know of an (objective) article that reviews and compares these solutions?